# How to solve android Edittext cursor position issue with Alignment span

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am working on simple android editor application.In that I have used Alignment Span.If I changed Alignment **Normal(LEFT)** to **Opposite(RIGHT)** or **Center** the cursor is not render correctly.

Device : Nexus devices.
API LEVEL :23

This issue is only on Nexus device which contain API LEVEL 23. The Nexus devices with API LEVEL below 23 working fine.Samsung devices with All API LEVEL working fine.

The Scenario of this issue is.

In my Application the Editor Screen have Edittext with three buttons(Alignment Left,Center,Right).Initially I have set Left Alignment.If i changed the Alignment **Left(Normal)** to **center** the cursor is **not drawn correctly**.The cursor remains same in the left position.But content changed to center.The expected behavior is both content and cursor moved to center position.

I attached image for your reference.
[This image contains the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZhQy.png)
,
[This image contains The exact behavior what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynl9W.png)
Here is my sample code:

```
mCenterAlignmentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Editable s = mEditText.getText();

                //Getting Left Alignment
                AlignmentSpan[] alignmentSpans = s.getSpans(
                        mEditText.getSelectionStart(), mEditText.getSelectionEnd(),
                        AlignmentSpan.class);

                for (AlignmentSpan alignSpan : alignmentSpans) {

                    int spanStart = s.getSpanStart(alignSpan);
                    int spanEnd = s.getSpanEnd(alignSpan);
                    s.removeSpan(alignSpan);  //Removed left Alignment

                    //set Center Alignment 
                    s.setSpan(
                            new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER),
                            spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

                }
            }

        });
```

Any suggestions for solving this issue.

Comment: Maybe yout can try something like 
`mEditText.setSelection(0);`
This will set the cursor on the start of your edittext. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Kristo1990 your reply is not related to asked question.